# C# WPF Border background Blur [FIXED]

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-8.0

***Problem solved, follow this path to give your window a corner radius: [CLICK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners)
Thanks to all of you.***

---

---

---

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dIm0.png

I have a method called Background Blur, but it completely blurs the background of the window, and even if the window is transparent, the corners of the window look bad. How can I ensure that this is applied only to the background of the border?

Blur.cs:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    internal enum AccentState
    {
        ACCENT_DISABLED = 1,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_GRADIENT = 0,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_TRANSPARENTGRADIENT = 2,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND = 3,
        ACCENT_INVALID_STATE = 4
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct AccentPolicy
    {
        public AccentState AccentState;
        public int AccentFlags;
        public int GradientColor;
        public int AnimationId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct WindowCompositionAttributeData
    {
        public WindowCompositionAttribute Attribute;
        public IntPtr Data;
        public int SizeOfData;
    }

    internal enum WindowCompositionAttribute
    {
        // ...
        WCA_ACCENT_POLICY = 19
        // ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public partial class Blurx
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern int SetWindowCompositionAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, ref WindowCompositionAttributeData data);
        internal void EnableBlur(dynamic Element)
        {
            IntPtr hwnd;
            PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(Element);
            hwnd = source != null ? ((HwndSource)source).Handle : IntPtr.Zero;

            AccentPolicy accent = new AccentPolicy
            {
                AccentState = AccentState.ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND
            };

            int accentStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(accent);

            var accentPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(accentStructSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(accent, accentPtr, false);

            WindowCompositionAttributeData data = new WindowCompositionAttributeData
            {
                Attribute = WindowCompositionAttribute.WCA_ACCENT_POLICY,
                SizeOfData = accentStructSize,
                Data = accentPtr
            };

            SetWindowCompositionAttribute(hwnd, ref data);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(accentPtr);
        }
        public void Show(dynamic Element)
        {
            EnableBlur(Element);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.Xaml.cs:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Blurx Blur;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Blur = new Blurx();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Blur.Show(Main);
        }

        private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DragMove();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Background="Transparent"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Title="MainWindow" Loaded="Window_Loaded" MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown" Height="500" Width="500">

    <Border CornerRadius="50" x:Name="Main" Background="#7FDE7AFF">

    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: That effect applies to a window but not a border.

Comment: How can I do it for the border?

Comment: You cannot. You can round the corners of a window though. [Apply rounded corners in desktop apps for Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners)